# Непонятное поведение программы

Tags: c++

Нужно написать реализацию метода шаблонного класса List для простых типов данных и строк(сhar*), которая будет загружать список с csv файла. Написал, но её поведение непонятно. (Программа падает на этапе компиляции).
*Допустим мы создаем список для типа double. Вызываем эту функцию и получаем ошибку в node.data = new char[strlen(str) + 1];, мол невозможно преобразование, хотя оно в эту ветку даже не должно зайти

```
bool List<T>::load(const char *filename) {
FILE*csv;
if ((csv = fopen(filename, "rt")) != NULL) {
    char str[128];
    fseek(csv, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(csv);    //size of txt file
    size = size - sizeof(char*);  //our lenght of file
    fseek(csv, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(char*)) {
        while (!feof(csv) && ftell(csv) <= size) {
            node_type node;
            fscanf(csv, "%[A-z.0-9];", &str);
            node.data = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
            strcpy(node.data, str);
            this->push_front(node);
        }
    }else {
    while (!feof(csv) && ftell(csv) <= size) {
        fscanf(csv, "%[A-z.0-9];", &str);
        this->push_front(*new node_type((T)(atof(str))));
    }
}
    fclose(csv);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Для начала: что непонятно? Мы телепаты, чтобы значть что вам не понятно.

Comment: Допустим мы создаем список для типа double. Вызываем эту функцию и получаем ошибку в  node.data = new char[strlen(str) + 1];, мол невозможно преобразование, хотя оно в эту ветку даже не должно зайти.

Comment: Что значит "получаем ошибку"? Программа падает в этой строчке? Почему не приведено описание ошибки?

Comment: error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать "char *" в "double"

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вы сказали "вызываем эту функцию", то есть вы успешно откомпилировали и запустили программу. А теперь вы нам показываете ошибку компиляции. Так как же вы "вызывали эту функцию", если у вас даже компиляция не проходит?

Comment: Вызываем в мэйне, и на этапе компиляции программа падает.

Comment: В С++ не имеет значения, "должно" ли оно зайти в эту ветку или "не должно". Код в любом случае должен быть корректным. Из этого требования есть исключения, но не в вашем случае.

Comment: Ну так ёлки палки - что вы голову дурите!

Comment: Хорошо, уточнил вопрос, извиняюсь за некоректную постановку)

Comment: Вы походу так и не поняли: у вас ошибка времени компиляции, а вы пишите так, буд-то это ошибка времени исполнения, что вводит в заблуждение. И компилятору плевать, что у вас там в цикле - он компилирует весь код, а не только то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите в шаблонном коде хотите включать или выключать ветки кода через ветвление времени компиляции (с включением/выключением проверки семантики), то вам нужен `if constexpr`, а не обычный `if`. Вам здесь никак не поможет обычный `if (typeid(T) == typeid(char*))`. В обычном `if` все ветки кода должны быть всегда корректны, независимо от того, заходит туда выполнение или нет.

Буквально это реализуется как

```
if constexpr(std::is_same<T, char *>::value)
```

Отдельно стоит добавить, что циклы с предусловием `!feof` - это практически всегда ошибка.

Comment: хорошо, я понял, спасибо большое, это расширило мои знания)буду пробовать)